# Remapping Caps Lock to Compose

Tags: linux, x11, console, keyboard-layout, compose-key

Because I now and then need to use scandinavian letters despite using US Dvorak as my layout, I would like to use Caps Lock as a compose key. (I don't need Caps Lock at all, I'm not a forum troll)

How would one accomplish this?

Using Linux Mint 17 with xfce, if that makes a difference.

For the record, I am the only user of this PC, and would prefer to have this be the system default, mainly in xorg, but also in tty if that's not too much drudgery.

Comment: The solutions for X and tty will most likely be quite different.

Comment: @Fabian Noted, thanks. Question updated accordingly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### X11 (classic)

Run the program `xev` from a terminal to see the keycode sent by the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key. That's the number just after `keycode` on the third line from the `KeyPress event` line corresponding to pressing the key. On a PC, the keycode is 66.

Create a file called `.Xmodmap` in your home directory and add the line

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
clear Lock
```

`Mode_switch` is the weird name that X11 gives to <kbd>Compose</kbd>. `clear Lock` is necessary to avoid the key occasionally acting like Caps Lock even though it isn't Caps Lock (`Lock` is the Caps Lock modifier, and some applications behave a bit strangely when modifier declarations and keysym declarations aren't consistent). Alternatively, you can use the lines

```
keysym Lock = Mode_switch
clear Lock
```

which causes any key currently sending Caps Lock to be rebound to sending Compose instead. Either way, you need to arrange for the command

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

to be executed when your session starts. This is a common convention, but not all combinations of distribution/desktop environment do it automatically. If yours doesn't, add the command to the list of commands executed at the session start (in the XFCE4 configuration editor, go to “Session and Startup” → “Application Autostart” and add that command).

### X11 (XKB)

XKB is neater and more powerful, but more cumbersome to use in general than xmodmap. There is a preset in the standard configuration to do what you want, so it's easy in your case: run the following command:

```
setxkbmap -option compose:caps
```

See the previous section for how to run this command when your session starts.

### Linux console

Find out the keycode of the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key. Run [`showkey`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey) on a text console, press <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, then wait 10 seconds for `showkey` to exit. On a PC, the keycode is 0x3a. You need to have the following line in your console keymap file:

```
keycode 0x3a = Compose
```

The default console keymap file is `/etc/console/boottime.kmap.gz` on Debian with the `console-tools` package. It may be a different file under Mint; this is the file that `loadkeys` is invoked on in the boot scripts. If you prefer, you can leave the distribution-provided files intact, create a file with the line above, and run `loadkeys /path/to/your/file.kmap` from `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: I tried the keysym method. While xev afterwards tells me that keycode 66 now corresponds to Mode_switch, it did nothing. What worked for me in X11 in the end was this: `setxkbmap -option compose:caps`.
The console approach worked like a charm.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I don't know why this was so hard to do. Other solutions either don't remove the default behaviour of caps lock or somehow bound my `b` key to escape instead.

Comment: The xkb method can also be persisted through x.org.conf by adding `Option "XkbOptions" "compose:caps"` to the appropriate section. It bears mentioning that this is going to re-map caps lock for *all* users.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: In particular, XFCE lets you configure CapsLock per Settings:

[image]

Switch to the 'Layout' tab, and disable 'Use system defaults'. Under 'Compose Key', select Caps Lock.

This will:

- Disable the CapsLock LED (if present)
- Disable the CapsLock function
- Enable the CapsLock as Compose key

I had never seen this option before, so this might be for recent XFCEs (4.16 in my case).