# Remapping Caps Lock to Alt (Meta) in GNOME / X11

Tags: x11, xorg, gnome, xkb, xmodmap

I'm looking to replace Caps Lock behaviour with the "Left Alt"/"Meta" modifier, in GNOME / X11.

There are a few options to replace Caps Lock with Super, Ctrl, etc. in GNOME Tweak Tool, which seems to use `xkb` via `dconf` internally, but there is *no option* to make Caps Lock behave as Meta there. Looking at `less /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev` confirms that this is not due to Gnome Tweak Tool, but an artifact of such a (named) rule just missing generally in X11.

Simply remapping via `xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 = Alt_L'` seems to work at first and actually sends Alt_L as confirmed by `xev`, and the Caps Lock LED doesn't change anymore, but no Alt/Meta behaviour happens when I press the key. For instance, CapsLock+B does not go a word back in the terminal as Alt+B does.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

After looking at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195160/222974, I found out that adding `clear Lock` to the xmodmap command makes it work. I then put these two commands in a (new) file at `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
keycode 66 = Alt_L
clear Lock
```

and set `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to run during GNOME session startup using https://github.com/hant0508/startup-settings.