# using caps lock led to show compose key state

Tags: linux, compose-key

i have remapped my caps lock to compose, just like [jarmund](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195065/remapping-caps-lock-to-compose) i don't need my caps lock. this however disables the caps lock led completely.
I'm looking for way to turn that led when i triggered the compose key and off when it's done

so far i have found can manually trigger the led by runnning `echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/input3\:\:capslock/brightness` as root